# ionic angular porject cordova-plugin-purchase get product is empty

Tags: cordova-plugin-purchase

here is my code samples.i add plugin cordova-plugin-purchase and after initialize and then register products.

put before order i am trying to get product but cant do that

```
 import   'cordova-plugin-purchase';
     
     
    
     
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-questions',
        templateUrl: './napp2.page.html' ,
        providers: [{provide: CdvPurchase.Store}]
    
    })
    
     
    
    
    
    CdvPurchase.store.initialize([CdvPurchase.Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY]);
    
    CdvPurchase.store.verbosity = 4;
     
    CdvPurchase.store.register([{
    
                id: 'urun1',
                type: CdvPurchase.ProductType.CONSUMABLE,
                platform: CdvPurchase.Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY,
              
              }]);       
    
     CdvPurchase.store.when().productUpdated(this.onProductUpdated);
    
     onProductUpdated() {       
            const product = CdvPurchase.store.get('urun1', CdvPurchase.Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY);
            console.log("PRODUCT: ", product)
          }
    
     
                CdvPurchase.store.when().approved((product) => {
                  
                  console.log('Purchase approved', product);
                   
                });
        
              
                CdvPurchase.store.when().finished((product) => {
                  
                  console.log('Purchase now owned', product);
                  
                });
                CdvPurchase.store.when().unverified((product) => {
                  console.log('    unverified', product);
                  
                });
                CdvPurchase.store.when().verified((product) => {
                   console.log('    verified', product);
                  
                  
                  
                });
    
    
    
        checkout(r){
    
          
         
          const product = CdvPurchase.store.get('urun1', CdvPurchase.Platform.GOOGLE_PLAY);  
    
        //   product is  !!!!!!! EMPTY!!!!!!!! so not working next codes...
    
    
         const sub = product.getOffer(); 
     
          
    
         CdvPurchase.store
          .order(sub)
          .then(() => {
            
            console.log('order placed', CdvPurchase.store.get("urun1"));
          })
          .catch((error: Error) => {
            
            console.log('error purchased failed', error);
            
          });
    
    
        }
```

CdvPurchase.Platform change to TEST not working

add billing key not workıng

upgrade ionic 6 not workıng, back to down version  now ionic 5  cordova 12.0.1

providers: [{provide: CdvPurchase.Store}]. move to app.model.ts   not workıng